# KDE Plasma black screen/no video output on login

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma, plasma5

**What happened:**

- I launched a game via proton(GTAV, lutris, epic games) and suddenly the screen turned black/switched to standby.
  My PC didn't react to anything; I had to shut it down by cutting off power.
- If I login with SDDM the same thing happens after the splash screen animation.
- I can switch to the tty but it needs almost a minute to "load" it.
- I have another DE/WM installed, it works flawlessly(same user)
- If I login to plasma with another user it also works as expected
- Removing the .config file in the users directory didn't change anything
- Idk if it is even related but trying to launch plasma_session from a terminal returns `org.kde.plasma.session: process job  "kcminit_startup" finished with exit code  0`
- Launching `plasmashell` from terminal in a WM spits out a few warnings but works just fine(plasma panels etc. appear)
- I couldn't find anything in /var/log and with journalctl
- KDE Plasma, Xorg, Arch Linux, Zen kernel

**What can I do?**

Has someone an idea what causes the trouble or how I can find useful (debugging)information/logs?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what exactly happened but after reinstalling all plasma packages it works just fine again.